# How to count specific range of values in specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use COUNTER but I can't seem to apply it on my case. So, my dataset in excel, and I would like to count the specific range of values on a specific column, like how many values are there of ≤0.25, >0.25 and ≤0.5, >0.5 and ≤0.75, >0.75 and ≤1.00

The example dataset looks like this, I would like to run it on Risk Level column

| No | Risk Level |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.619526363 |
| 2 | 0.297523821 |
| 3 | 0.244753675 |
| 4 | 0.750428792 |
| 5 | 0.495763972 |

Comment: I see you're new on SO, so just for the future, please post your data as text, instead of a picture, it's much easier to work with that (e.g. I could have used your data instead of generating some random numbers for this example)

Comment: Should the lowest bin include 0 or not, i.e. [0, 0.25], or (0, 0.25] (Or all negative numbers>)

Comment: sorry my bad, I have updated the question by providing some of the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut` to bin the data, then apply `value_counts`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'risk_level': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100),
})

pd.cut(df['risk_level'], [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
(0.75, 1.0]    28
(0.5, 0.75]    26
(0.0, 0.25]    26
(0.25, 0.5]    20
Name: risk_level, dtype: int64
```